# Silverlight: make a hyperlink button appear like a textblock?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make all the words in textblock that are URIs clickable. Here is the approach I've taken:

```
    private static void onTextChanged(DependencyObject dependObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WrapPanel wrapPanel = ((HyperlinkTextBlock)dependObj).LayoutRoot;
        wrapPanel.Children.Clear();

        // TODO: use a real wordbreaker?
        // adding an extra space to the end of the last word. Cry.
        IList<string> words = ((string)e.NewValue).Split(' ').Select(word => word + " ").ToList();
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Uri uri;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(word, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                // TODO the style is off - the text is too big
                wrapPanel.Children.Add(new HyperlinkButton()
                {
                    Content = word,
                    NavigateUri = uri,
                    TargetName = "_blank",
                    Margin = new Thickness(0),
                    Padding = new Thickness(0),
                });
            }
            else
            {
                wrapPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = word, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap });
            }
        }
    }
```

(I'd be totally up for a more XAML-oriented/declarative way of doing this, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.)

This works fine (except it'd be nice to use a real wordbreaker), except that the `HyperlinkButton` looks funny. It is too large, and the text won't wrap. It also seems to have some offset, which I've tried to fix through setting the `Margin` and `Padding` to 0, but it hasn't solved the problem.

Any other ideas? Really, I want `HyperlinkText` instead of `HyperlinkButton`, but I don't think that Silverlight 3 for the Windows Phone 7 offers that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I came up with by extracting the style for the hyperlink button and then making modifications to the areas that I cared about (that odd indent as you mentioned). That way the behaviour is exactly the same except for the things you want to change.

When you create the hyperlink button also set the style property as shown below:

```
var button = new HyperlinkButton
{
    ...
    Style = (Style) Resources["HyperlinkButtonWithNoIndent"]
};
```

Then in your page, add the following style to the resources:

```
<Style x:Key="HyperlinkButtonWithNoIndent" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextDecorations="Underline" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to do this with a `TextBlock` but it works with `Image` and `StackPanel` so it should work in your case too. Add a handler for the `Tap` gesture to your `TextBlock` and listen for it. Then, in the event handler, you can navigate to the URL.

```
TextBlock MyTextBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "Tap Me!" };
GestureListener listener = GestureService.GetGestureListener( MyTextBlock );
listener.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>( OnMyTextBlockTapped );
```

And the event handler looks like this:

```
void OnMyTextBlockTapped( object sender, GestureEventArgs e )
{
  // Navigate to URL
}
```

You could even animate the tap by starting a `Storyboard` in the event handler and performing the navigation when the animation completes.

Comment: adding a tap gesture to a textblock is equally viable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retemplating the control in blend? You should be in complete control of the presentation styling there for all consituent parts that make up the HyperlinkButton.

1. Rclick the control
2. Edit Template
3. Edit a Copy
4. Format away

You can reuse the resulting styling.